# Release - NS.time

Tags: javascript

I use this simple time method to time intervals.  It basically just consolidates some simple math.

```
/*time
**  dependencies - none
**  browser - unknown
**
*/
NS.time = (function () {
    var measurements = [];
    return function (control) {
        var index,
            intervals = [],
            time_current = new Date().getTime();
        if (control === 'start') {
            measurements = [];
            measurements.push(time_current);
            return;
        }
        if (control !== 'finish') {
            measurements.push(time_current);
            return;
        }
        if (control === 'finish') {
            measurements.push(time_current);
            index = measurements.length;
            while (index) {
                index--;
                intervals[index - 1] = (measurements[index] - measurements[index - 1]) + 'ms';
            }
            return intervals;
        }
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `start`, `middle` and `finish` are pretty much "verbs", why not make them actions of the object `time`? With that, an API like this would do:

```
$.time.start();
$.time.middle();
$.time.finish();
```

Further, a developer might run multiple instances of a timer to track more than just one something. Maybe a developer would like to run one timer for a page load while another set of timers for image loading. Thus, it would be better if we created instances:

```
//returns an instance id'ed by "pageload"
//passing blank creates only one anonymous timer
var pageLoadTimer = $.time('pageload');

//methods
pageLoadTimer.start();
pageLoadTimer.middle();
pageLoadTimer.finish();

//or simply chain
$.time('pageload').start();

//if you lose reference because you are not on the same scope
//or forgot to make one 
//or didn't make one at all and relied on the globality of jQuery
//calling a timer of the same name returns an existing timer
$.time('pageload').middle();
```

Anyways, with that adapted code, a result would be (as verbose as I can):

```
$.time = (function () {

  //our timer cache
  var timers = {};

  //extract common code
  function getCurrentTimestamp() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }

  //constructor to our instances
  //each with a name, time collection and difference collection
  function Timer(timerName) {
    this.name = timerName;
    this.times = [];
    this.perf = [];
    this.lastPerfIndex = 0;
  }

  //since the initialization has been done in the constructor
  //we remove it from start. but since start and middle does
  //the same thing, we merge it as "ping"
  Timer.prototype.ping = function () {
    this.times.push(getCurrentTimestamp());
    return this;
  };

  //calculate
  //a developer might want to get performance data
  //before actually finishing, thus the rename
  Timer.prototype.calculate = function () {

    //caching a few variables from the instance
    var perf = this.perf,
      times = this.times,
      timesLength = times.length, //getting n-1 length
      i = this.lastPerfIndex; //perfIndex explained further down

    //ping our last time check
    this.ping();

    //now a reverse loop would only make the code longer
    //a forward loop would make it much simpler
    while (i <= timesLength) {

      //now a developer might want to get performance data
      //but you would not want to calculate the entire set again
      //thus we store a last index, so the next call starts from here
      this.lastPerfIndex = i;

      //now since we are in order, use push instead
      //of manually jotting down the index
      perf.push(times[i + 1] - times[i]);
    }
    return perf;
  };

  //lets implement finish as a destroy function instead
  Timer.prototype.finish = function(){
    //remove this timer from cache
    delete timers[this.name];
    //return performance data
    return this.calculate;
  }


  return function (timerName) {
    if (timers[timerName]) {
      //if timer with name exists, return existing
      return timers[timerName];
    } else {
      //or cache and return a new one
      //creating a new one does not start it immediately
      //useful for stuff like preloading stuff or something
      return timers[timerName] = new Timer(timerName);
    }
  };
}());
```

In the end, usage might look like this:

```
//create a timer
$.timer('foo');

//aw snap! i forgot to reference, we can retrieve it
var foo = $.timer('foo').ping(); //lets start!

//some lines later, let's mark this period
$.timer('foo').ping(); //by retrieval
foo.ping();            //by reference "foo"

//let's get the performance array without killing this timer
var perfAfterTenKlines = foo.calculaate();

//let's get the performance array gain after 20 lines
//this time it calculates only data since last calculate
var perfAfterTwentyKlines = foo.calculate();

//ok we're done. lets get the final data and call it a day
var perfAfterOneMlines = foo.finish();
```